# How to make repository request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Repository pattern in laravel to fetch records from a table but getting error like

> "Target [App\Repositories\ThirdPartyRepository] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboardcontroller]."

This is the following structure I have

```
app ->
  Repositories
     ->Thirdpartyrepository.php
     -> Thirdpartyrepositoryinterface.php
     -> ThirdpartyServiceProvider.php
```

Thirdpartyrepositoryinterface.php

```php
    namespace App\Repositories;
    
    interface ThirdpartyRepositoryInterface
    {
        
        public function getAll();
        
    }
```

Thirdpartyrepository.php

```php
    namespace App\Repositories;
    
    abstract class ThirdPartyRepository implements ThirdpartyRepositoryInterface
    {
        
        public function getAll(){
            $getcmp= DB::table('xyz')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->select('name', 'id', 'created_at')
                ->get();
            return $getcmp;
        }
        
    }
```

ThirdpartyServiceProvider.php

```php
    namespace App\Repositories;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    class ThirdpartyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        
        public function register(){
            $this->app->bind(
                'App\Repositories\ThirdpartyRepositoryInterface',
                'App\Repositories\ThirdPartyRepository'
            );
        }
    }
```

Dashboardcontroller.php

```php
    use App\Repositories\ThirdPartyRepository;
        protected $thirdparty;
        public function __construct(ThirdPartyRepository $thirdparty){
                $this->thirdparty= $thirdparty;
            }
    
        public function getproducts(){
                $getCompanies=$this->thirdparty->getAll();
                dd ($getCompanies);
        }
```

Comment: maybe do a composer du. If that doesnt work, instead of string use the full class. Another note, in your dashboard controller, you are injecting the implementation. The main use of using an interface is to inject interface into controller or services where the class is needed. App bind is sort of where you define: when this interface is injected, use this model to execute it's functions.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. Can you please suggest the code?

Comment: I meant run `composer du` to rebuild autoload.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you are using an abstract class to implement the interface.. I think it should be a normal class, if composer du doesnt work, remove abstract and see if it works. Also, I am assuming that you have added your custom provider class to config providers array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain my comment in detail, in your Dashboard controller, you are injecting the implementation instead of the interface.
Your current code:

```
public function __construct(ThirdPartyRepository $thirdparty){
  $this->thirdparty= $thirdparty;
}
```

Main advantage to using interfaces is that it allows you to abstract your code. Since you are injecting the implementation, this advantage is lost. Say for instance, when you code a new implementation you would need to change this controller. Classes should be closed for modification as much as possible (SOLID principle).

You would need to change that method to:

```
public function __construct(Thirdpartyrepositoryinterface $thirdparty){ //inject interface
  $this->thirdparty= $thirdparty;
}
```

And my third comment:
Instead of abstract class, you should have a normal class implementing the interface.

```
class ThirdPartyRepository implements ThirdpartyRepositoryInterface //remove abstract
{ 
    public function getAll(){
```

And you need to add your service provider to the providers array in config.php.

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\ThirdpartyServiceProvider::class, //your new service provider.

],
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to bind an abstract class to interface. Change

```
abstract class ThirdPartyRepository
```

to

```
class ThirdPartyRepository
```

and also you should inject the interface not the concrete class like this

```
public function __construct(ThirdpartyRepositoryInterface $thirdparty){
    $this->thirdparty= $thirdparty;
}
```

Otherwise your whole purpose of using contracts for binding is meaningless. Bind interface to implementation.